# Seeing the digits of long floats

Tags: python, floating-point

If you key in a very long float and store it in some variable `x`, you will get a shorter number if you call `print(x)` or something like that.

Is there any way to overcome this and see all the digits stored inside the variable, or at least show a certain number of digits?

For example, say I want the square root of two:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
>>> math.modf(math.sqrt(2))
(0.41421356237309515, 1.0)
>>> sqrtOfTwo=math.modf(math.sqrt(2))
>>> print(sqrtOfTwo[0]+sqrtOfTwo[1])
1.4142135623730951
```

When I called `sqrt`, I got a float that was shown to 16 decimal places. However, when I called `modf`, a float was shown to 17 decimal places.

Say I want to see the square root of 2 to, say, 20 decimal places. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the floats upto a given precision you may use `.format()` method as:

```
print "{:.20f}".format(math.sqrt(2))
>>> 1.41421356237309514547
```

Or as per the comment by Lexy, you may also use:

```
format(math.sqrt(2), ".20f")
```

Comment: Or call format like: `format(math.sqrt(2), ".20f")`. Either is good!

Comment: Or `print "%.20f"%math.sqrt(2)`

Comment: I know I'm being troublesome, but is there any way to display it as a float without the int() function?

Comment: By the way, I would put you as an answer right now, but I can't. It says I can only answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @JAW, can you elaborate what so you mean by *float without the int()* ?

Comment: @Z, sorry, I just realised that that would be impossible.